# How can I draw a png ontop of another png?

Tags: c++, c, libpng

How can I "draw"\"merge" a png top of another png (background) using libpng, while keeping the alpha section of the png being drawn on top of the backhround png. There does not seem to be any tutorials or anything mentioned in the documentation about it.

Comment: by definition if you put any image on top of another image it will lose its transparency, unless you want to 'cut holes' in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libpng is a library for loading images stored in the PNG file format. It is not a library for blitting images, compositing images, or anything of that nature. libpng's basic job is to take a file or memory image and turn it into an array of color values. What you're talking about is very much out of scope for libpng.

If you want to do this, you will have to do the image composition yourself manually. Or use a library that can do image composition (cairo, etc).